# What is the function of Ether in operating an application on the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: ether, gas

What is the relationship between the price of Ether and the usage of the Ethereuem blockchain?

Or is a Ether coin simply a means of holding a piece of the value of the Ethereum blockchain (like a shareholder in a publically listed company)? (I know that gas is used to operate Ethereuem blockchain applications...so then I am wondering what the point of the Ether token coin is in terms of running the applications on the Ethereum blockchain).

Comment: Also related: [What is meant by the term “gas”?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas)

Answer (score 1):

Ether is used as an incentive for miners to process transactions, and to protect the network from being spammed since each computational step costs small units of ether.

Related

- [What is ether? How is it different from other tokens such as bitcoin?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/398/what-is-ether-how-is-it-different-from-other-tokens-such-as-bitcoin)
- [What is meant by the term "gas"?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas)
- [What exactly is Ether currency in Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27483/what-exactly-is-ether-currency-in-ethereum)

Answer (score 0):

Every transaction be it from account to account or a transaction with a smart contract, costs GAS. 
Gas has a value in ether, so basically each transaction costs ether, and that's what ether is used for.